# A SpamAssassin filter for empty HTML part

Tags: spam, spamassassin

A new kind of spam's been getting through my defenses lately with the following common characteristics:

1. The message itself is of type `multipart/mixed` with two parts.
2. The body of the spam is in the first part, of type `text/plain`.
3. The second part is of type `text/html` and is *empty*:

```
----f3c31d93219a26172136ed0487d80041
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

----f3c31d93219a26172136ed0487d80041--
```

How can I add a rule for recognizing such messages so SA can reject them?